# I can't find the external IP for Minecraft Java multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't know where to find the external IP I've heard about for Minecraft Java multiplayer, because I have friends I want to play with that live half a state away and whenever I open to LAN it only shows the port number in the chat.

Comment: Opening to LAN only works on LAN

Answer (score 0):

“Open to LAN” only allows people on the same network to play with you. If you want to play with your friends in another state, you’ll need to set up a server. If you don’t want to go through all the work associated with this, you can use a free hosting service such as aternos.org.

Comment: You can use services like Hamachi and use its ipv4 with the port instead of setting up a server and having to deal with portfowarding which is a pain.

Comment: thank you for your help